# Camera screen size in iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, screen-resolution, iphone-5

I am designing a camera app in ios. I see that Video uses the whole screen in iphone 5 but camera does not. So I wanted to know the screen width and height of the camera screen that the default camera uses to design my app.

Answer (score 0):

That's because unlike the feed from the video camera, the feed from the camera has a different aspect ratio from the devices screen. To rectify this, you'll need to resize your preview layer to match the aspect ratio of the feed, or you'll need to change the video gravity property of your video preview layer.

Once of these should suffice:

```
[myPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

[myPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResize];
```